# BLE how to downlaod all data from device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building an app that download all information from a BLE device. This BLE device have two characteristics to read.

I should to read these characteristics until the BLE device have data storage. So I created a loop and wait until the BLE device have data, I call the method readCharacteristic.

So I create a queue with my characteristic to read. This is the code:

```
if(ReadQueue!= null && ReadQueue.size()>0){
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                int index =0;
                                for(index=0; index < ReadQueue.size(); index++){
                                    mGatt.readCharacteristic(ReadQueue.get(index));
                                }

                            }
                        }).start();
                    }
```

But with this code, I can read only the first characteristics, if I call sleep after this line, I can read all characteristics.

```
 mGatt.readCharacteristic(ReadQueue.get(index));
```

Now, is there a way to download all characteristics in a loop ???

Answer (score 1):

Calling readCharacteristic in sequence (without delay) will not work.

You have to wait for [onCharacteristicRead](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int)) for the first call before initiating the second one.

When you connect to the BLE device using connectGatt, you have to provide a BluetoothGattCallback. Implement onCharacteristicRead in that BluetoothGattCallback object, it will be called after each readCharacteristic actually finish. Inside that function you should read the next characteristic in queue until there is none.

Comment: how can I wait that onCharacteristicRead complete your code before initiating the second one ???

Comment: @bircastri edited to add some more description. If you can show how you maintain the ReadQueue object, maybe I can write a short sample.